# Recommended isolation paper for hobby circuitry

Tags: transformer, insulation

I'm having a hard time finding out what type of insulation is enough for my projects.

I will be building this: [STM32 OLED Soldering Station Case Temperature Controller T12 KR BL ILS BC2 Handle Electronic Soldering Iron Tips 220v 70W](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/STM32-OLED-Soldering-Station-Case-Temperature-Controller-T12-KR-BL-ILS-BC2-Handle-Electronic-Soldering-Iron/32789158005.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.169.eekXTW&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10068_10171_10084_10083_10119_10080_10082_10081_10301_5360014_10110_10136_10303_10137_10111_10060_10112_10113_10155_10114_10154_438_10056_10055_10054_10182_10059_100031_10099_10078_10079_10103_10073_10102_10120_10189_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051-10102,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_2&btsid=a41e2dad-2e22-4f57-97ac-22d6f533efba&algo_expid=48c143c7-6765-46bd-848c-a12d87a4e692-21&algo_pvid=48c143c7-6765-46bd-848c-a12d87a4e692)

I'm wondering what type of insulation paper is needed for the metallic body, to protect the internal transformer and other bits.

This video shows what I'm going to be doing: https://youtu.be/25rww-pXqr0?t=5m39s

He states any insulating material is enough (0.3mm?). i'm wondering what is best bang for the buck so to speak. Looking at Aliexpress/Alibaba that is. I'm also planning to use the paper in a few other projects!

Comment: Why do you think you need paper? The kit looks complete. Paper wouldn't be a good choice as an insulator (except in oil-filled switchgear or transformers) as once it gets damp it loses its insulation. Sorry, I am not going to watch a video for you. Post a screengrab if there is anything in particular you want us to see.

Comment: @Transistor The video starts at 5min 39seconds (you immediately see the insulation). Ah ok, well what do you recommend? Electric tape on the inside? (Just want to learn good practice, that's all)

Comment: That first link was apparently to a questionable site, and I'm certainly not gonna sit thru a video.  The pertinent information needs to be here.  Closing.

Comment: I can't give you an answer but I think this is a valid *general* question (as long as you don't make it a *shopping* question). It's late here in the UK, but to help you keep the question "on track" and help those who want pictures, I've uploaded 3 screengrabs from your video, which you can use to update your question (if you want to): https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7hyA.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vVN8.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/und5e.png and here is a Digikey datasheet for a similar product: http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/GC%20Electronics%20PDFs/560_560-100.pdf  Good luck!

Comment: The insulator is called "Fish Paper" its more than just paper, there are other insulating sheet materials too

Comment: @OlinLathrop You've never heard of Aliexpress or Alibaba? Alibaba is Amazon but in Asia (Alibaba owns Aliexpress). I've ordered countless things from it, never had an issue! :) 
 Some more info: https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/248345

Comment: Of course I know of Alibaba, and also its reputation as not someplace I want to buy electronic components from.  Some things popped up in my browser when I went there, so I immediately came back.  I was willing to overlook that, but then I saw you expected us to watch a video.  Not gonna happen, and you've lost any slack you otherwise had by trying that.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I'm a developer and can say that their website is not malicious in anyway :) As answered to Transistor who also mentioned he will not watch the entire video I wasn't expecting you to (that would be crazy), if you look at the URL parameters you can see that the video starts at 5minutes 39seconds, in other words it immediately shows the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown, that kit is a death trap waiting to kill an inexperienced buyer. Like you. You do not need paper. You will need insulated hookup wire to make connections. You will also need 4 longer screws in order to mount the power supply. Drill the bottom of the case to fit the mounting holes on the supply. Purchase 4 standoffs about 1/4 inch long which have a center hole (either threaded or not) which fits the screws, along with 4 nuts and lock washers which fit the screws. Push the screws through the bottom of the casing. Put a standoff on each (using threaded standoffs will make this easier, since you can screw them on and not have to worry about the screws falling out). Then put the supply board on the screws, then use the nuts/lock washers to hold the supply in place. Tighten everything down. The standoffs will hold the underside of the supply away from the metal case and no insulation will be needed.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know, thank you so very much!

Answer (score 2):

For a hobby circuit, if in doubt, wrap it in electrical tape.  Paper is not a good insulator since it can be abraded thru easily, and doesn't insulate well when wet or damp.

Make sure the electrical tape isn't adding thermal insulation to things that need to dissipate significant heat.

Hot glue can also be useful in the short term.

Answer (score 1):

Air gaps needs to be  3mm from smooth AC surface to metal earth ground,  Paper needs to be stiff so  solder tips won't cut thru. I prefer Mylar or Polycarb sheets but you might be able to cut from PVC packaging material 0.3mm min.

As long as it wont short out if you step on it or spill coke on it. ( Official UL safety test is to use a hammer and coke)

if there is clearance, check if nylon washers will work with TH wires sheared.